# Crystal Report rendered differently on server and development machine

Tags: .net, asp.net, crystal-reports, report

I'm working on a ASP.Net application (.Net 1.1) with Crystal Reports 2003. I have created a report with some Text Objects and Data Fields (Report title, Company title, Date, etc.) which are retrieved from a DataSet. Most of them are using the default font (Times New Roman / 10pt).

Everything looks fine on the development machine, but when I install the application to the server and print the report, practically all of the fields are "messed up".

By "messed up" I mean:

- fields look as if their width and height have been reduced which results in cropping top and/or bottom part of the Text Object or wrapping the content and displaying it in two rows
- vertical spacing between Text Objects is slightly increased
- vertical spacing between report segments have been increased

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the server machine I had two different printers installed a POS printer which was not used anymore, and the "Microsoft XPS Document Writer". After deleting both of these, and reconfiguring the other ones to same settings as the development machine had. Reports were fixed.

I'm not sure if this helps anyone, but if you encounter a similar problem, try fiddling with your printer settings, because this behavior seems to be related to printer, not Crystal Report itself.

Comment: Any other ideas? I am having issues like this but the printer settings do not seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that the rpt files have a "no printer" option that, when checked, fixes these odd adjustments due to the installed/default printers of the machine rendering the report.

https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/1001496

We found this after word wrapping started happening subtly earlier on reports with no software changes at all outside of normal Windows updates.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late response, but I'd like to expand on Miljenko's answer a bit after encountering a similar problem and solution. I am using CR Developer, version 11.5.12.1838 on a Windows 7 machine.

The rendering of the report appears to depend heavily on the driver used by the system's current default printer. When using a point-of-sale printer with a generic/text only driver as the default, my reports rendered very strangely, with highly uneven character and line spacing. Once I switched my default printer back to a traditional inkjet with a fancy driver, the report rendered appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the font you are using is installed on the development machine. That was my case.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).