# Crystal Report in visual studio .net 2008 on local machine and server with design differences

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

i have a vb .net 2008 console application that generate a pdf based on a report made in crystal report (.rpt) developed on a local machine, it work fine but when i installed the same application on the server and its opened in the vb .net 2008 installed in the server the fonts looks differents (they both have arial inline, i dont use cssclass on the project) and some controls have different sizes, so i have to make differents changes in the proyect.

I check the crystal report.engine dll and are the same in both vb. studio

Anyone know how to fix this problems or why it presents the differents between the applications?

Report in Local machine
http://img684.imageshack.us/img684/4383/reportlocalmachine.jpg

Report in server
http://img703.imageshack.us/img703/3804/reportserver.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have experienced this same thing.  One thing that you'll find with Crystal is that it's tethered to the printers you have installed (which can problematic when rendering on different computers).

Try removing printers you don't need and/or make sure the same default printer is set and then try it again (just as a test).  There are cases where I have an Excel output and the only way to make the Crystal Report longer to place all of the columns is to install a printer that allows for a forever long page width.

The printer has always been the issue/fix for me when inconsistencies in exporting to PDF (or other formats) come up.  Also, I found another thread where they state the same thing:

[Crystal Report rendered differently on server and development machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804956/crystal-report-rendered-differently-on-server-and-development-machine)

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much with your answer, it was exactly what I need, i change the default printer and it generated without a problem, i fixed the problem a while ago so i wanted to thank you for the contribution

Comment: Any other ideas? I am having issues like this but the printer settings do not seem to make any difference.